# Laravel Passport Illegal offset type

Tags: api, laravel-passport, laravel-5.7

I have installed Laravel Passport, followed all the instructions from multiple websites and I cannot make it run properly.

When I called the middleware auth:api I keep on getting the same error.

```
ErrorException (E_WARNING)
Illegal offset type
```

Error that occurred in AuthManager class on guard method  in this line

```
public function guard($name = null)
{
    $name = $name ?: $this->getDefaultDriver();

    return $this->guards[$name] ?? $this->guards[$name] = $this->resolve($name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It probably means that you don't have the `auth` middleware configured properly.

Passport defines some routes using the middlewares `['web', 'auth']` (that are default for Laravel), so check if you have them on `Http/Kernel.php`.

If not, you can use the default middleware configuration:
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.7/app/Http/Kernel.php#L54

Comment: I have it in that way